# Can a docker image break for different versions of Docker engine?

Tags: docker, containers

I am new to Docker. From introductory materials, I learned that Docker engine forms an abstraction layer above the operating system. This seems to be similar to JVM and .NET runtime. So if Docker gets a new version, will some functionalities break ? Do we need to be aware of versions of Docker runtime in our environments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker is very different from a JVM or other programming runtime environment. You are running your application on the Linux kernel as you always have. What it provides is an isolated namespace and other restrictions to run that application inside a jail.

Since your image includes everything needed to run your application by design, the only reason you wouldn't be able to run it in the future is if the image format changes (which could happen with OCI standardization, but I'd expect a long transition period where multiple image formats are supported). The only other way your application wouldn't be portable is if you either change your platform (e.g. ARM instead of x86), but that would also break any attempt to run your application outside of a container too.